# Plotting numpy.bytes_ data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data I am loading using recfromtx. The imported data looks like this:

```
x = [b'79453,13' b'63140,62' b'50203,12' b'39890,62' b'31640,63' b'25171,88']
y = [b'1,060623' b'1,055831' b'1,056309' b'1,064114' b'1,064976' b'1,072364']
```

the type of each element is `numpy.bytes`.

but when I plot this I get a weirdly compressed plot that also does not represent my data.

[image]

How do I convert my data or fix the plotting?

Comment: You need to convert your data to numbers. Possibly you best check how you got that data as bytes in the first place.

Comment: How does one do that convert the data? I've tried the avaible dtypes in np.recfromtxt
but none of them fix the issue.

Comment: So the problem is that you use a comma as decimal separator. You probably need to use the `converters` argument and supply a function that replaces the comma by a dot.

Comment: I can make this for a string, but the data is "bytes" class and .replace does not work for these.Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, but why is it of type `byte`? That seems undesired and shouldn't be the default.